# Rails 3 Returning All Columns from a Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, arel

I'm trying to join two tables and return all columns, not just the ones associated with the model.

I have something like that looks like this:

```
Comment.joins(:user).select("*")
```

The SQL looks fine, but still, it only returns the comments and none of the user info associated with it.

How can I retrieve `*` and not just `comments.*`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about

```
comments = Comment.includes(:user).all
```

Now `comments` is going to be an array so you'll have to loop through it to see all the users.

```
#won't work
comments.user 

#should work
comments[0].user

comments.each do |comment|
    puts comment.user.name #or whatever
end
```

Comment: Still can't get the User info to show. Head over to Mishka's and help me with this ;)

Comment: I've been up too long ;). This works. I wanted to make sure everything is being eagerly loaded.

Comment: Looks like .all isn't necessary on the end (for me at least). Makes the code slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
comments = Comment.joins(:user).includes(:user)
```

But here's what I think is happening, if you are viewing the output in your console windows, I think that the console output only reflects/inspects the root level object that is returned.

I just did an experiment where I executed the above code. The terminal output recorded that it fetched the comments but didn't mention the associated user. Next, I shutdown the database so that a second query could not be executed against the database, then asked for the associated user, e.g.

```
comments.user
```

The console output the user, which proves that it has already been eagerly loaded, because no database connection was attempted.

Comment: Interesting.  I was wondering the same thing. Although caching of queries could make it confusing, you also might notice whether or not a query is fired off when you execute `comments.user`.

Answer (score 1):

Comment.select('*').includes(:user)

Comment: Right - I wasn't sure if you were concerned about SQL or just getting the data back. In this case you get both Comments AND Users back without having to go back to the DB.

Comment: Just do Comment.select("Comments.*, Users.*")

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates has good tutorial on this subject.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading-revised?autoplay=true